# Repeated references with multibib

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, multibib

I am trying to cite multiple references, sorted by reference type (journal vs. conference). Some of the journal references cite the corresponding conference paper where the results originally appeared.

However, when I cite the conference paper in the journal reference, the conference paper bibliographic details re-appear in the journal bibliography, like so:

[J1] Blah blah. Journal paper. Extended version of [C1].

[J2] Blah blah. Conference paper.

[C1] Blah blah. Conference paper.

I only want the citation (eg. [C1]) and not the repeated reference (eg. [J2]).

Below is a MWE of my document code.

**.tex file**

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[resetlabels, labeled]{multibib}

\newcites{%
    J,%
    C%
    }%
    {%
    Journal Articles,%
    Conference Articles%
    }

\begin{document}

\nociteJ{DoeKnuthJournal}
\nociteC{DoeKnuthConference}

\bibliographystyleJ{unsrt}
\bibliographystyleC{unsrt}

\bibliographyJ{./Publications}
\bibliographyC{./Publications}

\end{document}
```

**.bib file**

```
@article{
    DoeKnuthJournal,
    author  =   "Doe, John and Knuth, Donald",
    title   =   "A really good paper",
    journal =   "Journal of Good Papers",
    note    =   "Extended version of GP 2000 article \cite{DoeKnuthConference}",
}

@inproceedings{
    DoeKnuthConference,
    author  =   "Doe, John and Knuth, Donald",
    title   =   "A really good paper",
    booktitle = "Proceedings of Good Papers (GP 2000)",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the `bib` file into two files, one for journals and one for conferences:

**.tex file:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[resetlabels, labeled]{multibib}

\newcites{%
    J,%
    C%
    }%
    {%
    Journal Articles,%
    Conference Articles%
    }

\begin{document}

\nociteJ{DoeKnuthJournal}
\nociteC{DoeKnuthConference}

\bibliographystyleJ{unsrt}
\bibliographystyleC{unsrt}

\bibliographyJ{PublicationsJ}
\bibliographyC{PublicationsC}

\end{document}
```

**PublicationsJ.bib:**

```
@article{
    DoeKnuthJournal,
    author  =   "Doe, John and Knuth, Donald",
    title   =   "A really good paper",
    journal =   "Journal of Good Papers",
    note    =   "Extended version of GP 2000 article \cite{DoeKnuthConference}",
}
```

**PublicationsC.bib:**

```
@inproceedings{
    DoeKnuthConference,
    author  =   "Doe, John and Knuth, Donald",
    title   =   "A really good paper",
    booktitle = "Proceedings of Good Papers (GP 2000)",
}
```

[image]

This is somewhat unsatisfying, because it would be nice if you can leave all the references in the same `bib` file, but this seems to be a known limitation of `multibib`; see Section 1.3 of the [documentation](http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/multibib.pdf).